# Searching for questions with no answers using a filter

Tags: support, unanswered-questions, search

On Stack Overflow, how can I search for questions that contain a given keyword and have no answers?

Comment: See all search options here: http://meta.stackoverflow.com/search

Comment: Also, put the cursor in the search box and hit enter, and you'll get the same page of info that Goran has provided.

Comment: By "keyword", do you mean "tag"?  If so, surround your tag in square braces like this: [answers:0 \[xml\]](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0+%5Bxml%5D).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just add [answers:0](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=answers%3A0) in the search text field.